# Solution to a quadratic Diophantine equation in two variables

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Have been exploring a roundabout solution to a linear Diophantine equation:

$$36x^2y^2+ a^2-2bxy-25(x^2+y^2)=0$$
$$x,y\in\Bbb Z; \qquad0 < x,y$$

where a, b are known positive integers.

Considering the example of:

$$36x^2y^2+ 646^2-7802xy-25(x^2+y^2)=0$$
What is the best approach?

Comment: Letting $z=x+y$ and $w=xy$ in the example and using discriminant of quadratic gives a pell equation.

Comment: @Ghartal yes, except it works out to a difference of squares, so that the number of solutions $(z,w)$ is finite and found by factoring an integer (which is also a difference of squares, but complete factoring would be needed)

Comment: @WillJagy That's right. Coefficient of $z$ is a perfect square.